# How to prove an implication

Tags: logic

If we have two statements $P$ and $Q$, we generally show that $P\implies Q$ by direct work or we show $\neg Q \implies \neg P$. However, if I were to say the following:

Assume $P$ to be true. Now suppose $Q$ were not true. I then work from this to show a contradiction (that $P$ in fact can't be true). Hence it cannot be the case $Q$ were not true if $P$ were true. So $Q$ is true. Therefore $P \implies Q$.

Is the above a viable way of showing $P \implies Q$ or is it not logically equivalent to the statement $P \implies Q$?

Comment: After reading your OP a second time, I now understand what you meant. Yes, what you described is one of many ways you could derive $P \to Q$. However, if you can use the approach you described, then it is also possible to simply assume $\neg Q$, derive $\neg P$, and infer the conditional $\neg Q \to \neg P$, which is logically equivalent to $P \to Q$. So, a simple subproof of your own proof will do the trick. @X Stanton describes this approach below.

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need to make that first assumption. If you start by supposing $Q$ is false and then show that $P$ is false, that is precisely a proof by contrapositive! No need to show any contradictions or to assume that $P$ is true.

Comment: Great insight that all the OP needs to show $P \to Q$ is a subproof of the proof they orginally offerred. +1 upvote! However, the OP wants to know if their approach is a "viable" way of deriving $P \to Q$, which it is. You may want to acknoweldge that.